# Optimize an Trace matrix form

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace

In paper " Generalized Low Rank Approximations of Matrixces

``[...] the minimization in Eq. (1) is equivalent to minimizing
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\mbox{trace}(D_iD_i^T) -  2\sum_{i=1}^n\mbox{trace}(LD_iR^{T}A_i^{T}).~~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$
It is easy to check that the minimum of $(3)$ is obtained, only if $D_i= L^{T}A_iR$, for every $i$. This completes the proof of the theorem. $\square$''

The dimensions of the matrices are as follows:

$A_i$   is $r \times c$

$L$ is $r \times l_1$

R is $c \times l_2$

$D_i$  is $l_1 \times l_2$

why it says $D_i = L^T \cdot A_i \cdot R$ is the optimal solution? we substitue the solution to the objective function, it come out zeros but how to proof this is optimal?
Thanks

Comment: As a non-mathematician, I hate it whenever any paper say's "It is easy to check."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (3) is seperable for all $i$, thus, you can differentiate (3) with respect to $D_i$ to get
$$
2D_i-2L^TA_iR = 0
$$
since $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\text{Trace}(XX^T)=X+X=2X$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\text{Trace}(CXB)=C^TB^T$. Thus $D_i=L^TA_iR$ for each $i$.